# how to set an ID to a newly opened window?

Tags: javascript

I have a window which I open from my javascript code:

```
 window.open('/Item/Article/' + item.ItemID(), 'ItemArticle', 
'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=' + res.height + ',width=' + res.width + ',
 left=0', null);
```

when a certain condition is met I want to change the html address of that window,ie reload it to a new location.

how can I set an ID or an anchor to the window which I open manually, so that I can use this ID to reload that window with a new location.

Comment: try remove `ItemArticle` from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to 1) have a reference to your window and 2) state the name when using [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

You can modify your window by choosing the same window name (the second argument).

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://google.com","myWindow");
// opens SO in the same window
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com","myWindow");
// the following will only work if it's the same domain, else subject to SOP -
// so in the case of initially opening it with google, this won't work!
myWindow.document.location.href = "/example/test.html";
// closes your window
myWindow.close();
```

So in your case, the following line should work:

```
window.open('newURL','ItemArticle'/* optionally: ,'Parameters'*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the window in a variable and then control it just as you would normally control a window object.

The following code will open a new window, and after 4 seconds, reload to a new location.

```
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.focus();
setTimeout(function(){
    myWindow.document.location = "http://www.google.com";
}, 4000);
```

Comment: sindenote: `myWindow.document` is subject to SOP, so it will fail for a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the URL of Window B from window A, you can do `window.open` and provide the same name as the second argument. This will simply "re-open" the already open window, and redirect it to the new URL.

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','googleWindow');
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','googleWindow');
```

Above code will open a window at Google, and instantly redirect it to Stack Overflow

Uncertain if this automatically focuses the window however!

Comment: He wants to redirect an already opened window from the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way to access function in parent windows from where the child windows was opened.

`window.opener.ParentWindows(); //Here ParentWindows() is userdefined function coded by me in parent windo`w

Comment: He wants to redirect an already opened window from the parent window.